# understanding memory consumption: free the memory of a StringIO?

Tags: python, memory, buffer

I'm curious to understand why in the first example, the memory consumption happens like I was imaging:

```
s = StringIO()
s.write('abc'*10000000)
# Memory increases: OK
s.seek(0)
s.truncate()
# Memory decreases: OK
```

while in this second example, at the end, I use the same thing but the memory does not seem to decrease after the truncate method.
The following code is in a method of a class.

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import requests

self.BUFFER_SIZE = 5 * 1024 * 2 ** 10 # 5 MB
self.MAX_MEMORY = 3 * 1024 * 2 ** 10 # 3 MB

r = requests.get(self.target, stream=True)  # stream=True to not download the data at once

chunks = r.iter_content(chunk_size=self.BUFFER_SIZE)
buff = StringIO()

# Get the MAX_MEMORY first data
for chunk in chunks:
    buff.write(chunk)
    if buff.len > self.MAX_MEMORY:
        break

# Left the loop because there is no more chunks: it stays in memory
if buff.len < self.MAX_MEMORY:
    self.data = buff.getvalue()

# Otherwise, prepare a temp file and process the remaining chunks
else:
    self.path = self._create_tmp_file_path()

    with open(self.path, 'w') as f:
        # Write the first downloaded data
        buff.seek(0)
        f.write(buffer.read())

        # Free the buffer ?
        buff.seek(0)
        buff.truncate()

        ###################
        # Memory does not decrease
        # And another 5MB will be added to the memory hiting the next line which is normal because it is the size of a chunk
        # But if the buffer was freed, the memory would stay steady: - 5 MB + 5 MB

        # Write the remaining chunks directly into the file
        for chunk in chunks:
            f.write(chunk)
```

Any thoughts?
Thanks.

Comment: How do you measure "*Memory increases*"?

Comment: The OS often leaves memory allocated to a process when freed in case they are about to use it again. How do you measure memory usage?

Comment: Well, I do not do it the best way because I look at the memory consumption of the python process. But it definitely increases by 5Mb and then by 5Mb again when hitting the last for loop.

Comment: try a forced garbage-collection: `import gc; gc.collect()` - does it change something?

Comment: gc.collect does not change anything :/ The memory still doubles.

Comment: How do you "*look at the memory consumption of the python process*"?

Comment: Do you ask out of curiousness or do you have a memory-leak problem? furthermore i guess you just showed us a small snippet out of your code, which means the problem may lay in the hidden parts.

Comment: @Rob: I look at the memory consumption of the whole python process from the task manager (I'm on Windows).

Comment: @Don: I don't have a memory leak problem. The code I put here is all it is about and it is in a method. When I call this method, I observe this memory behavior. When the method has finished, the memory comes back to what it was before starting. Well, interesting.

Comment: i guess you memory gets lost either in chunks or data. so truncating the stringio won't do anything. try deleteing chunks oe eventually data. that should do it `del chunks`